# Bad accents and "ñ" in my postgres database

Tags: postgresql, encoding, pentaho, kettle, diacritics

I have an ETL process collecting data from a PostgreSQL database and xls files and inserting in a PostgreSQL database that process occurs great in a local DB in Postgres 14 with UTF8 codification and Spanish_Cuba.1252 collation but when I execute that process in dev which is in a docker container with Postgres 15.4 and UTF8 encoding with collation en_US.utf8 the words with accents and "ñ" looks like an interrogation symbol(see the picture[bad accents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cY1m2.png)), what can I do to fix this?

To solve this I've tried to mock the environment that dev's has in my local machine, so I installed a Postgres 15 with the same encoding and collation and the process occurs fine as well, so now I'm thinking that the problem is in my ETL tool, which I've been using for more than 10 years and always worked great, now I'm using the 9.4 version of that tool (Pentaho Data Integration) also known as kettle, there I’ve tried using parameters in the connection to specify the encoding needed, I’ve checked the xls files encoding as well

Comment: Somewhere in your etl/pipe there is a step that is moving data that is not set to a codepage that supports the characters that are being garbled. Does the ETL for this pipe run in the same environment regardless of where the postgres database is located? Is there a point where the data hits the OS upon which the postgres database is running? Could that be the culprit? Sometimes trying to get unicode (or in this case, a codepage that is just slightly more robust than ascii) through a complex pipeline can feel like making stars align.

Comment: You have to figure out how your characters are encoded in the database and in the application.And I don't believe that there is an encoding 1952.

Comment: Also, a place to check, is whatever client you are using to query and display the results. If that differs between dev and prod, then that might cause what you are seeing.

Comment: @JNevill the ETL process is implemented in Pentaho also known as kettle, and it is running inside the same PostgreSQL server, to query the data i used PgAdmin and also de console and in both places the data is wrong

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe it was a typo I fixed it already, thank you

Comment: Just for reference: this is the same as [this pgsql-general thread](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CAD_aniHBxNsTFjJO%2BdSaifQwtf2dEX2FKezOaic5KgJ_NCGNTw%40mail.gmail.com).

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe is that not allowed?

Comment: That is perfectly fine, but being able to read the thread might prevent dupplicate effort.

Answer (score 0):

we have found the solution to our accents problem, a colleague of mine got the idea to use xlsx instead of xls and the magic happened, thanks to all for your support